# ASP.NET Use SqlDatasource on master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, sqldatasource

I'm trying to populate the site menu on the site master page, according to the current user's role. For some reason, the C# code behind file does not recognize the SqlDataSource nor some other hidden fields that I put on the mater page's aspx code.
here's my code:

```
ASP:
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="getButtons" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RMSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="sp_getSiteMasterButtons" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="idsid" Name="idsid" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>

  <asp:HiddenField ID="idsid" runat="server" />

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

C# code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        idsid.Value = Environment.UserName;
        getButtons.DataBind();

    }
}

Error   1449    The name 'idsid' does not exist in the current context
Error   1450    The name 'getButtons' does not exist in the current context
```

Thanks all

Comment: Can you please post the first line of your .aspx file? Check what your .aspx inherits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define the MasterType so that the child page knows what class the Master Page is. This will make the Master Page strongly typed.

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx).

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Masters/Master1.master" %>
```

Also, I'm not sure if controls declared on the ASPX page are by default public. So you may need to add them as a property on the Master Page so that they're publicly accessible from other classes.

```
public SqlDataSource MasterDataSource {get {return this.getButtons;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

should be

```
getButtons.DataBind();
```

Comment: You are correct, I just changed it's name but it doesn't work even if I correct it.

Comment: You have two IDs called idsid, I would rename one of them.

Comment: that's true again, but still does not work. even if i don't use the hidden field, just the SqlDataSource - the C# file won't recognize it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
         Inherits="SiteMaster" CodeFile="Site.Master.cs" %>
```

in your

```
       Site.Master
```

Comment: I have it, this is the code on the top. BTW it's just Site.Master, no aspx extension             <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">